# How to render link inside string

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this string:

```
'You can visit this <a target="_blank" href={"www.pageName.com"}>page</a> to see more things.'
```

I would to display it in React app without using third part libraries.

```
 <div onClick={handleClick}>
        {descr}
 </div>
```

The result:

[image]

What I want:

[image]

Comment: See [dangerouslySetInnerHTML](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml)

Comment: I sow it but it's not safe, correct?

Comment: The “dangerous” part is having a string with arbitrary html in it.  How dangerous it is depends on the html.